# Jcombobox reading from textfile with 2 mapping value

Tags: java

I've got a text file which look like below :

```
ap apple
og orange
gp grape
```

I would want the jcombobox to show `apple,orange,grape` in the dropdown but when select it output `ap` , `og` and `gp`

Comment: nothing special, simple job, is about customized Renderer, voting to close as too broad

Comment: Create a class to hold the two values. Override `toString()`  in that class to return just the second value. Read the file, split each line and create an object from your class. Add as instance of the class to the combo box for each line you read. This way upon selection, you have access to `ap` or `apple` if you need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use vector to store first part of String .and then get `getselected` index from  combobox.then take value out from vector from same index .vector indexes and jcombobox indexes has mapped .

you should add second part to combobox while adding first part to vector

```
v1.add(split[0]);
jComboBox1.addItem(split[1]);
```

this is example code

```
Vector v1;//field

BufferedReader br = null;         
try {
     br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("test.txt")));
     String line;
     v1=new Vector();
     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         String[] split = line.split(" ");
         v1.add(split[0]);
          jComboBox1.addItem(split[1]);
     }
      br.close();

 } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
 }
```

in combobox action performed

```
String get = (String) v1.get(jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex());
System.out.println(get);
```

Comment: Consider using the try-with-resources statement: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: so vector vs map which consider better considering the dropdown list must display in alphabetic order.

Comment: the tricky part is 
v1.add(split[0]);
jComboBox1.addItem(split[1]);

you should add first part to combobox next part to vector

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own ComboBoxModel.

```
private static class Fruit {

    public final String id;
    public final String name;

    public Fruit(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

private final List<Fruit> fruits = Arrays.asList(
        new Fruit("ap", "apple"),
        new Fruit("og", "orange"),
        new Fruit("gp", "grape")
);

    DefaultComboBoxModel<Fruit> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
    for (Fruit fruit : fruits) {
        model.addElement(fruit);
    }
    jComboBox1.setModel(model);
```

Here I just let the ComboBox return the Fruit on getSelectedItem. Using a Map one could easily let return the short ID. by overriding methods.